# Generate all n-leaf arbitrary trees

Tags: python, tree, binary-tree

I need to generate all possible arbitrary tree topologies for a given number of leaf nodes, with the limitation that every non-leaf, non-root node must have a sibling (to prevent infinite recursion). In particular, I'm looking for a clean Pythonic way of doing this (though any and all advice is welcome).

So, for instance, for n = 3, I'm looking for the following output:

> - (1 2 3)
> - ((1) 2 3)
> - (1 (2) 3)
> - (1 2 (3))
> - ((1) (2) 3)
> - ((1) 2 (3))
> - (1 (2) (3))
> - ((1) (2) (3))
> - ((1 2) 3)
> - (((1) 2) 3)
> - ...

In particular, (1) is a valid tree for n=1, but ((1)) is not, as it includes an internal node which has no sibling. This keeps the set of possible trees finite.

(I'm agnostic about ordering: Solutions may treat (1 2) and (2 1) as either identical or distinct. That is, I will eventually need them to be distinct, but that can easily be accomplished in a second step.)

### Relevant Background

There is a homomorphism defined between binary trees and arbitrary trees, such that there are as many binary trees with k nodes as arbitrary trees with k + 1 nodes. See [Eric Lippert's excellent explanation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/04/22/every-tree-there-is.aspx). Lippert gives an easy means to generate all arbitrary trees for a given number of *nodes*, but I'm looking for all arbitrary trees with a given number of *leaves* and variable numbers of nodes.

There's a [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242117/what-python-code-generates-all-possible-groupings-trees-for-binary-operators) enumerating n-leaf binary trees in Python. But the corresponding arbitrary trees will have fewer than n leaves: My constraint on leaf nodes is on the arbitrary trees, not on the binary representations thereof.

When you translate an arbitrary tree into a binary tree, a leaf in the arbitrary tree corresponds to a node in the binary tree which has no left child. Thus, it seems like a solution might start from a set of leaf nodes (defined to have only right branches) and internal nodes (which require at least a left branch) and enumerate possible combinations. I can't quite see my way to the full solution, however.

Comment: I don't see an obvious way to enumerate those trees. I believe the problem can be solved if you can also solve the problem "how many ways can you insert m matched pairs of parentheses in a string of n  such that no matched pair is *directly* inside another"; perhaps that will help.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this, Eric! I've looked a little bit at inserting matched parens, but I'll think about it some more and update the question if I come up with anything.